# imakeindex and edindex behaviour in section-titles

Tags: reledmac, reledpar

I saw some questions regarding indexing and reledmac/relepar but I think this might be kind of a now one. Please correct me, if I'm wrong.

In my MWE (well its not so mini) I get a wrong index output, if I put an \edindex command into the eledsection{} argument. It seems that imakeindex gets confused with the other linenumbers.

I'm using reledmac 2.31 and relepar 2.22.2. Anyone has an idea how to solve this?

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, pagesize=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}
\usepackage[series={A,B,C}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}

\makeindex[name=persona, title={Index der Personen}]


%%BEGIN DOCUMENT \begin{document} \lineation{page} \lineationR{page}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\eledsection*{\textsc{C.}\edindex[persona]{C., S.} in Epistola ad \textsc{H. B.} M.DC.VI}
\pend\pstart
Placuit mihi tuum\edindex[persona]{B., H.} tricinium, et video te non tironem, sed exercitatum esse in hujusmodi harmoniis condendis. Ego sic statuo neminem futurum bonum melopoëtam\edindex[persona]{Melopoëta}, nisi.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}


\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumberingR
\pstart
\eledsection*{C. in einem Brief an H. B.}
\pend\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumberingR
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\printindex[persona]

\end{document}
```

Comment: if it is a bug, please open a github issue

Comment: I've opened an issue. I think it might be a bug. In my project It happens any time I have \edindex in a title-environment.